# How do I sum all the columns with the same header into one column in excel?

Tags: excel

I am using a football dataset where I have changed all the countries to specific geographical areas in their column headers. What I want to do is I want to add up all the columns with the same geographic value with all the values added up.

This is how my data looks like:

[image: Excel sheet of data]

The value of #players should still remain the same after condensing the data. I tried using the data function, but I could not figure it out.

My output should ideally look like a column with all the EUs added up, the AFRs added up etc.

Comment: You question, as it stands, is simply asking us to do all the work for you (which is not the intent of SO). See [help – on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Recommend looking into `SUMIF`. Once you give that a try, if still having issues, come back, show your work and explain in what way it's not working.

Comment: Hi, I apologize, I am still new to this. I have used Sumif and this is the formula I used : =SUMIF(D1:CB1, CL1,D2:CC89) where the criteria was set to EU. It just summed up the number of EU columns that I have.

Comment: Fair enough :) When you do add code, please do so by editing your post (versus including in comments) and make sure it's formatted as code (see editing `?`). Separately, that formula appears to trying to add add values on all rows (versus row by row). If that's what you're trying to do, suggest also 1) Reduce the data example to a smaller sample and 2) add a column with the expected results in it (colored differently or bolded) to make it clear it's your results column).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually unclear as to exactly what it is you're trying to do.
Here is an example use of `SUMIF` that addresses one possible interpretation:

```
=SUMIF($B$1:$E$1,F$1,$B2:$E2)
```

And here is an image showing how and were that formula would be used in this sample table:
[image]

If this doesn't address what you're aimed for, could you make an effort to do as I have done and show a small sample with the expected results.

Comment: Thank you! I used SUM to do it, but I will try this as well!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it using the SUM function.

I used SUM(C2,C6,C7....) every column that had an EU in it and did the same for the other headers.